# nginx location with url/#

Tags: backbone.js, nginx

Im using backbone and nginx.  I have a location as follows:

```
    # will be handled with nginx
    location ~* ^/ {
        root /Users/myname/Projects/cms/source/cms;
        access_log off;
        expires max;            
    }
```

Using the following url works:

```
http://localhost/console.html
```

Using the following url fails with a 404:

```
http://localhost/console.html/#login
```

Ive tried the following:

```
location  ~* \/(#)$ {
location  ~* \(#)$ {
```

But doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

**Update**
The location was actually correct.  Thanks to mu for clearing up it that it wasn't my attributes but the trailing slash.

Comment: The server will never see the fragment so the `#login` isn't the problem. Maybe the trailing slash is the problem.

Comment: Your right the mistake was in my url.  After i fixed it worked fine

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

The location was actually correct. Thanks to mu for clearing up it that it wasn't my attributes but the trailing slash.